# I am trying to get a result of addition of number array in Javascript but its showing Nan result

Tags: javascript

// I want to add a number array elements but the result is showing Nan why so

```
let numarr = [5598, 4589 ,25465164]
    let len = numarr.length;
    let i,  numval = 0;
    for(i=0; i <= len; i++) {
      numval +=  numarr[i];
    } 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numval;
```

Comment: The answer you picked first is much better than the one you picked now, as it both explains what you asked for, and shows an alternative. Please consider picking the best answer, not the shortest answer.

Comment: Yes first answer I picked  had really simple explanation  but I saw your solution is also good as reduce method is exposed to me..

Comment: Why then did you finally pick the answer with no explanations at all?

Comment: I am new to stack overflow. I just wanted to thank everyone who spare their time and provided me with solution. I don't know wheather selecting first or last answer will rank the people I have no idea about that.

Comment: It's not about ranking people, its about picking the answer that explains and solves your problem best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` should be smaller than `len` not `smaller or equal`.

Example:

```js
let numarr = [5598, 4589 ,25465164]
let len = numarr.length;
let i,  numval = 0;
for(i=0; i < len; i++) {
  numval +=  numarr[i];
} 

console.log(numval)
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because of the `<=` in `for-loop`. If you use `<=` then loop will run past the length of the array and it will try to access the element that is not present.

If you are trying to access the element that is not present then it will return `undefined`. Addition of a number with `undefined` will give you `NaN`

Either use `numarr.length - 1` or `i < len`

```js
let numarr = [5598, 4589, 25465164]
let len = numarr.length;
let i, numval = 0;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  numval += numarr[i];
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numval;
```

```html
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
```

**Alternate solution:** You can also use reduce here to achieve the same result

```js
let numarr = [5598, 4589, 25465164]

const numval = numarr.reduce((a, c) => a + c);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numval;
```

```html
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
```

Comment: I recommend explicitly adding the start value for `a`. Also for a beginner an explanation of what is going on will be helpful, as well as speaking variable names instead of `a` and `c`.

Comment: much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your array has 3 elements at indices 0, 1 and 2. So your arrays should run from 0 to `array.length - 1`. If you tries to access `numarr[3]` the value will be `undefined`. Adding `undefined` to a number is `NaN` that means not a number

It should be `i < len`

```js
let numarr = [5598, 4589, 25465164];
let len = numarr.length;
let i, numval = 0;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  numval += numarr[i];
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numval;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you made has already been pointed out in numerous other answers, I would like to show you an alternative in modern JS.

Instead of using an index-based for-loop, Javascript has a specialized function for what you want to do, which is called [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). It is called once for each array element, adds its `value` to the `accumulator` and returns the accumulator after the last iteration. The start value `0` for the accumulator is the second parameter.

```js
const numarr = [5598, 4589 ,25465164]
const sum = numarr.reduce((accumulator, value) => accumulator+value, 0);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sum;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Question is why NaN! !!

Comment: @Nitheesh That part has already been answered numerous times, I'm showing the modern alternative to this which cannot run into any sort of index confusion.

Comment: Reverted the dv

Comment: much appreciated connexo